# Palindromic pairs in an array of words

Tags: java, algorithm, palindrome

I came across a code for palindromic pair problem, using Trie.

```
public static class Trie {
    int pos;
    Trie[] nodes;   // consider xyxabc. if current trie is 'a'. Then a.nodes has information. It means string after a is palindrome
    List<Integer> palins;
    public Trie() {
        pos = -1;
        nodes = new Trie[26];
        palins = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

public static void add(Trie root, String word, int pos) {
    for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        char ch = word.charAt(i);
        if (isPalindrome(word, 0, i)) { // check if substring(0, i) is palindrome.
            root.palins.add(pos);
        }
        if (root.nodes[ch - 'a'] == null) {
            root.nodes[ch - 'a'] = new Trie();
        }
        root = root.nodes[ch - 'a'];
    }
    root.pos = pos; // if it is xyxcba. Until now, the node should be at x.
    root.palins.add(pos);
}

public static void search(Trie root, String[] words, int i, List<List<Integer>> ans) {
    int len = words[i].length();
    for (int j = 0; j < len && root != null; j++) {
        if (root.pos >= 0 && i != root.pos && isPalindrome(words[i], j, len - 1)) {
            ans.add(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {i, root.pos}));
        }
        char ch = words[i].charAt(j);
        root = root.nodes[ch - 'a'];
    }
    if (root != null && root.palins.size() > 0) { // assume 'xyxabc' is in trie, now try 'cba'
        for (int j : root.palins) {
            if (j != i) {
                ans.add(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {i, j}));
            }
        }
    }
}

public static List<List<Integer>> palindromePairs(String[] words) {
    List<List<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<>();
    Trie trie = new Trie();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        add(trie, words[i], i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        search(trie, words, i, ans);
    }
    return ans;
}

public static boolean isPalindrome(String str, int i, int j) {
    while (i < j) {
        if (str.charAt(i++) != str.charAt(j--)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Could any one please help me understand, what are we trying to do in this line in **add** method.

```
if (isPalindrome(word, 0, i)) { // check if substring(0, i) is palindrome.
            root.palins.add(pos);
        }
```

and here outside of FOR loop why do we need to add:

```
root.palins.add(pos);
```

I have seen this code from here:
http://www.allenlipeng47.com/blog/index.php/2016/03/15/palindrome-pairs/

However i am still finding it difficult to understand this approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the blog post you're linking to does not do a good job explaining the core idea of the solution. This is what probably makes it difficult to understand the code.

Let's start with the problem (as you're not quoting it):

> Given a list of unique words. Find all pairs of distinct indices `(i, j)` in the given list, so that the concatenation of the two words, i.e. `words[i] + words[j]` is a palindrome.
>
> **Example 1:** Given `words = ["bat", "tab", "cat"]`
>   Return `[[0, 1], [1, 0]]`
>   The palindromes are `["battab", "tabbat"]`
>
> **Example 2:** Given `words = ["abcd", "dcba", "lls", "s", "sssll"]`
>   Return `[[0, 1], [1, 0], [3, 2], [2, 4]]`
>   The palindromes are `["dcbaabcd", "abcddcba", "slls", "llssssll"]`

When do two words `words[i]` and `words[j]` fulfill the condition of `words[i] + words[j]` to be a palindrome?

- If `words[i]` and `words[j]` have equal length, then `words[i]` must equals the revers of `words[j]` (or vice versa).
- If one of the words (say, `words[i]`) is longer, then it must end with the reverse of `words[j]` and the rest of `words[i]` must be a palindrome.
  For example, take `lls` and `s`. `lls` ends with `s` and `ll` is in palindrome. So `s` + `lls` is the palindrome.

Having noticed this, we basically need an efficient method to check if some `words[i]` ends with the reverse of `words[j]` and that the remainder of `words[i]` is a palindrome.

This is implemented using a `Trie` structure which builds a radix tree over reversed words. The blog post gives a good example of the build `Trie` for words `"cbaaa", "bc", "abc"`:

[image: Trie for words <code>"cbaaa", "bc", "abc"</code>]

This `Trie` makes it pretty efficient to search for prefixes. For instance searching for `cba` (reverse of `abc`) gives the node starting `cbaaa`.

I think the main problem understanding the code is due to poorly named fields (and the code is generally a bit messy). It is not clear what `pos` and `palins` are so this probably causes you trouble.

`pos` of the given `Trie` node is simply the index of the word formed by sequence of nodes from the "root" to the given node. In the example above, `cbaaa` has the index `0`, `bc` the index `1` and `abc` the index `2`. Corresponding nodes have the appropriate `pos` values.

`palins` is a bit more interesting. When building the `Trie` up to some node, we have some common prefix. For instance, when the `Trie` is built up to the node `a` in `c-b-a-a-a` we have the common prefix `cba`. But what we also need to check quickly is that the rest of the word is palindrom. This is what `palins` is for. `palins` saves indices of words which start with the common prefix we have so far in construction AND where the rest of the word is a palindrom. In our example, `cbaaa` starst with `cba` and the remainder `aa` is a palindrom. So the index `0` of `cbaaa` in `words` will be added to `palins`. If there were something like `cbatt`, its index would have also added to `palins`.
We also need to consider the case like `abc` - `cba` where there is no remainder. This is done by adding the index of the word to `palins` of the node of the last symbol (this is why you see another `root.palins.add(pos);` outside the `for` loop).

Now it should be more or less clear how the search method works:
* For each word, search the prefix, equal to this word reversed. If there is such prefix, there will be a corresponding node in the `Trie`.
* If such node is found, check `palins`. This will effectively give indices of workds which are palindrome-pairs to the given word.

For example, when we search for `abc`, we'll find the first `a` node in `c-b-a-a-a`. The prefix `cba` equals `abc` in reverse. The `palins` of this `a` node will contain `0` (index of `cbaaa` in `words`), so we'll get `[2, 0]` as one of the results.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const words = ["abcd", "dcba", "lls", "s", "sssll"] 

const Name =(arr)=>{
  const output =[];
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
  let word1 = arr[i];
  for(let j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
    if(i!==j){
      const concatword = word1 + arr[j];
      const reverse = concatword.split("").reverse().join("");
      if(concatword===reverse) output.push([i,j])
    } 
  }
}
  return output
}
console.log(Name(words))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).